# Homebrew/Python errors after trying to install Certbot

Tags: python, homebrew, certbot

I'm trying to install Certbot on my macOS machine (10.14.4) to generate a certificate, but as usual, some Homebrew errors are standing in the way.

After running, `brew update` and `brew install certbot`, I tried a command based on `sudo certbot certonly -a manual -d example.com --email your@email.com`, but I get `sudo: certbot: command not found`. I also tried `brew upgrade`.

`brew doctor` shows:

```
Warning: The following directories do not exist:
/usr/local/sbin

You should create these directories and change their ownership to your account.
  sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin
  sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/sbin

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar.
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
  python@2
  python
```

`brew link python` returns `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/Frameworks`.

For some reason, it looks like I have 2 versions of Python installed now and I don't want to run any of the commands that Homebrew suggests until I know I need to. `python --version` returns `Python 2.7.10`.

Should I uninstall one of my Pythons? Is one of them the system version or is that a third installation somewhere else? Which one should I symlink and how do I get the certbot command working? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks
sudo chmod 1777
```

then

```
brew link python3
```

this will install your python3 on your mac
i would not deinstall python 2.7 because there are still a lot of scripts depends on python 2.7!